# How to keep while loop in bubble sort function in C

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I'm trying to make my own bubble-sort function in C.

As you can see in the code below this, I'm trying to only using `while` / `if` loop to create this function. I put 5 numbers `(1,3,2,5,4)` so that size of array of this would be 5, and I got 5 (I checked it with Python(C)tutor. However, It works well until `tab[j]` gets 3. I'm trying to figure it out, but couldn't figure it out why it keeps going out when `tab[j]` gets 3.

Could you anybody explain what's wrong to me? I would appreciate it.

Here is my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_sort_integer_table(int *tab, int size)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int tem;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while(tab[i] < size)
    {
        if(tab[j] > tab[j+1])
        {
            tem = tab[j];
            tab[j] = tab[j+1];
            tab[j+1] = tem;
            printf("%d ", tab[j]);
            j++;
        }
        else if(tab[j] < tab[j+1])
        {
          printf("%d ",tab[j]);
          j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int tab[] = {1,3,2,5,4};
    int size = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(*tab);
    ft_sort_integer_table(tab, size);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure it out, but couldn't figure it out why it keeps
>   going out when tab[j] get 3.

From your code above, j increment in the same fashion as i. That means both variables will have the same value since j will be incremented by one after the if-then-else statement, and i will also be incremented by one at the end of each loop. Therefore, tab[j] is referencing the same value as tab[i]

With that being said, the boolean condition in the while loop checks whether the value in the tab[i] is less than the value of size.

When i == 3, tab[i] == 5 since in the loop, only the values in the array of index less then i are swapped/changed. Since the size variable holds that value of 5, tab[i] < size will result in a false value and exit the loop.

More information on bubble sort can be found here, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an inner loop in your bubble sort, which is responsible for moving the largest element to the back and performing swaps `i` times (these large elements are "bubbling up"). Start the inner loop at `0` on each iteration and iterate through `size - i` (we know that the last `i` elements are sorted and in their final positions).

`i` controls your outer loop and should be incremented at the end of the loop (just as you would with a `for` loop). `j` controls the inner loop and should be incremented at the end of the loop.

While you're at it, it's a good idea to move your printing out of the sort function, which causes an unnecessary [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) and might frustrate your debugging efforts.

Also, it's worth mentioning that (1) `for` loops are more semantically appropriate here and (2) there is an optimization available by adding a boolean--as soon as you have a pass through the inner loop that performs no swaps, end early!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_sort_integer_table(int *tab, int size)
{
    int i = 0, j, tem;

    while (i < size)
    {
        j = 0;

        while (j < size - i)
        {
            if (tab[j] > tab[j+1])
            {
                tem = tab[j];
                tab[j] = tab[j+1];
                tab[j+1] = tem;
            }

            j++;
        }

        i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int tab[] = {1,3,2,5,4,6,7,1,5,6,8,9,1,4,5,1,2};
    int size = sizeof(tab) / sizeof(*tab);
    ft_sort_integer_table(tab, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d ", tab[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 7 8 9
```